# Error al tratar de hacer un formulario con 7 campos: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, netbeans-8.2

Quisiera saber el porque de este error. Estoy haciendo un programa de prueba en Java usando Netbeans y necesito insertar 7 campos en una BD y a la hora de enlazar el JPanel correspondiente al JFrameForm agrego este código

```
private void mit_AgregarInventarioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JInternalFrame vhija = new JInternalFrame("Agregar Inventario",true,true,true,true,true,true,true);
    AgregarInventario hijo = new AgregarInventario();
    
    vhija.add(hijo);
    vhija.pack();
        Dimension d = this.getSize();
        int x = (d.width-vhija.getWidth()/2);
        int y = (d.height-vhija.getHeight()/2);
    vhija.setLocation(x, y-20);
    vhija.setVisible(true);
    escritorio.add(vhija);
}
```

[image: Ejemplo del formulario]

y me da este error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - no suitable constructor found for JInternalFrame(java.lang.String,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean) constructor javax.swing.JInternalFrame.JInternalFrame() is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No existe ningún constructor para `JInternalFrame()` que reciba 8 argumentos por eso tienes ese error, el más similar acepta 1 argumento String y 4 argumentos boolean:

```
JInternalFrame(String title, boolean resizable, boolean closable, boolean maximizable, boolean iconifiable)
```

Los constructores disponibles para ese objeto los podes encontrar en la documentación de Oracle: [JInternalFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html)

Después podes usar los distintos métodos de JInternalFrame() para cambiar esos valores:

```
JInternalFrame vhija = new JInternalFrame("Agregar Inventario");
vhija.setClosable(true);
vhija.setMaximizable(true);
vhija.setIconifiable(true);
vhija.setResizable(true);
```

Comment: si, me di cuenta de eso, solo que: si mi formulario necesita la inserción de 7 elementos, ese código con solo 4 elementos me será de utilidad o me impedirá hacer lo que deseo? @infinit3Loop__

Comment: Es que no tienen nada que ver las opciones de JInternalFrame() con la cantidad de campos de tu formulario. JInternalFrame es la ventana de tu formulario no su contenido, los campos son JTextFields y las etiquetas de esos campos son JLabels, el boton es un JButton

Comment: Asi que no, eso no debería impedirte hacer un formulario con los campos etiquetas y botones que quieras